# How pitch is changed in harrier jet(vertical landing and take off aircraft)

Tags: lift, pitch

How pitch is changed in harrier jet and lift is achieved?Is it same principle like conventional fighter jets like f16 etc? What about drones quadcopter etc do they also follow same principle?

Comment: F-16 cannot land or takeoff vertically. And what do you mean with "etc"? There are drones with and without wing, they work differently and also here not all drones can land/takeoff vertically

Answer (score 3):

Pitch and roll is achieved by generating forces far away from the Center of Gravity (CoG), causing a moment which in turn pitches or rolls the aircraft. Imagine pushing or pulling on one side of the aircraft in flight: you will accordingly pitch or roll the aircraft depending on where you pushed or pulled.

The question is therefore: How does the harrier (or drones, quadcopters etc.) generate a force far away from the CoG?

**1. The Harrier** achieves that over **ejecting air out of nozzles** as far away from the CoG as possible. For this it uses relatively small reaction control nozzles at its wingtips, and at the far front and back. These are pressurized using bleed air from the jet engine. The pilot can individually activate each nozzle up or down in order to generate forces which then will result in a pitching or rolling moment such that the aircraft follows the pilots command. You can see the arrangement in the picture below. Note that this method of generating control forces *is only done in hover or near-hover* flight. During conventional horizontal flight, the harrier achieves control over its control surfaces, the same way as any other fighter jet.

Also note the big **Swiveling nozzles** near the fuselage. These generate pure Lift: They generate a lot of thrust upwards to keep the Harrier in the air as the reaction control nozzles are not powerful enough to lift the entire aircraft.  But because these swiveling nozzles are mounted close to the CoG, they *cannot* be used for roll or pitch control. Thus, the **Swiveling nozzles** generate the lift during hover-flight, while the **reaction control nozzles** generate control moments to enable the pilot to control the aircraft. This system is only active during *Hover* flight (therefore at zero or close to zero forward airspeed). When the pilot wants to fly horizontally, the swiveling nozzles are swiveled backwards, and the reaction control nozzles are deactivated. The Harrier will then fly forwards just as a normal jet would do. In normal horizontal flight, lift is generated with the wings, and control is achieved via the control surfaces, just as a normal jet would do.

[image: Reaction control valve diagram, taken from https://documents.techno-science.ca/documents/CASM-Aircrafthistories-AV-8AHarrier.pdf]
Picture taken from [Canada aviation museum](https://documents.techno-science.ca/documents/CASM-Aircrafthistories-AV-8AHarrier.pdf)

**2. Quadcopters** in principle do the same thing: They generate thrust far away from their CoG by speeding up or down the rotors. Increasing the speed means more thrust, therefore generating a higher force which just as in the case of the harrier generates a moment which pitches or rolls the quadcopter. However they do **not** have swiveling nozzles, because they do not need to: The rotors of are drone are powerful enough to lift the entire vehicle. Therefore the generation of lift and the generation of control moments of drones are both combined in the rotors. Note the difference to the Harrier: The Harrier needs **Lift** nozzles, and **control** nozzles. The Quadcopter can combined both of these in the form of propellers.

Answer (score 0):

It diverts bleed air to valves to control attitude in hover:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Can you please link to the source of the image?